# reversing an array AND assigning it to new array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I would simply like to reverse the order of a currently existing array and assign that reversed order to a new array WHILE keeping the original array intact (not reverse).

I tried to make the reverse happen to my new array (b). However, when I print the ORIGINAL array after the reverse algorithm, it prints in the new reversed order. I would like for this array to stay intact in the original.

Here is my code where I have two arrays: n and b, where n is my original array and b is my reversed array.

```
public void setUpArray(){
    user = input.next();
    char [] n  = user.toCharArray(); 
    char [] b = n;
    boolean ok;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));


    for(int i = 0; i < n.length / 2; i++) // reverses the array
    {
        b[i] = n[i]; 
        char temp = b[i];
        b[i] = b[b.length - i - 1];
        b[b.length - i - 1] = temp; 
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n)); //this prints in reverse for some reason
```

Currently if I input "hi" into the scanner, this is my output

```
[h, i] <-- original array (n)
[i, h] <-- reversed array (b)
[i, h] <-- orignal array (n) prints in reverse, why???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make this assignment

```
char [] b = n;
```

it means there is only one array object referred by both the `n` and `b` variables. Create a new array in order for the original array to remain unchanged:

```
char [] b = new char[n.length];
```

If you do that, your code for reversing the array should also change. You should take the input values from `n` instead of from `b`. You don't need the `temp` variable at all.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n.length / 2; i++) // reverses the array
{
    b[i] = n[b.length - i - 1];
    b[b.length - i - 1] = n[i];
}
```

Comment: I figured thats where the problem was. However, when I do this, my reversing algorithm does not work. It only reverses 0th index and stops. Any ideas why?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts In your current implementation you should copy the entire input array to the output array before you start to reverse it (since otherwise `b[b.length - i - 1]` is not initialized` when you swap it with `b[i]`), but a better solution would be to copy it in reverse order.

Comment: By copy the input array into the output array, do you mean to assign them to each other like I did originally? Sorry I'm a little confused, I would appreciate if you could elaborate.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts See the edit. You don't have to copy the un-reversed input array, just copy the elements of n to b in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks so much, that clears a lot up. Funny thing though about your edit, if the array is an odd number length, it doesn't show the middle index in the reverse array. Very strange..

Comment: @NicholasRoberts In that case, just add one iteration to the loop - `for(int i = 0; i <= n.length / 2; i++)`